# If I have a device that transmits data over Bluetooth, is it possible to get at that data via a different device with my own custom code?

Tags: bluetooth, automotive

I am looking at building a tyre pressure info system for my car, but would like to make use of the existing receiver and transmitters that screw onto your tyre's valve stems.

A [model exists that transmits the data over Bluetooth](http://www.conrad.com/ce/en/product/620834/ITMPS-MONITOR-PRESSURE), which you are then meant to download an app to view the data.

I am wondering if it's possible, if I had a Bluetooth chip on my computer, to tap into that data and build my own custom interface for it? Is it complicated or something someone in my experience could do rather straightforwardly (software engineer with some electronics knowledge)?

Comment: Probably - the question would be how tricky it is to figure out what they are sending.  Mobile apps aren't particularly hard to reverse engineer, and interaction with platform APIs such as bluetooth can't be obfuscated.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks. If I connect it to my computer, I assume there is some tool I can use to see data being transmitted?

Answer (score 1):

(I would rather leave this as a comment, but don't have enough rep)

If your computer has bluetooth transceiver you can use a packet sniffer program like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) (Unix and Windows) to investigate the packets and try and understand the data transmission protocol.

http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Bluetooth

Be aware though that you will be looking at packets meant for the data transmission layer (See the [OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)) which means that there will be data bits in the packet relating to the transmission hardware along with the data, which will be encoded in a specific way for use with software.

Comment: This is only true for (as stated on the page you've linked) your own machine. You won't be able to see data link layer without an analyzer capable of logging all 79 BT channels at once (very expensive) or using a device like Ubertooth (non-trivial) and running Wireshark on Android device to see packets to and from the app is going to be even more difficult. @OP see if the authors are willing to open the code for you; even for a fee this will likely be your cheapest option.